# How to Choose the string which starts with small letter from a list

Tags: java

If I have a list containing [StudentName, ResigsterNumber, Department, grade , comment]

How can I choose only those words which starts with small letter. i.e. (grade and comment)

Comment: What have you tried ? At least try something before asking us some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8 it is pretty easy:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("StudentName", "Department", "grade", "comment");

List<String> filteredList = list.stream()
    .filter(s -> Character.isLowerCase(s.charAt(0)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(filteredList); // prints "[grade, comment]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the ASCII value of the first letter of each word. The ASCII value of lowercase letters is between 97 to 122.
 Loop through the list and store the String in variable `str`

```
int i=str.charAt(0);
if(i>=97 && i<=122){
      // this is a word starting with lowercase letter
      System.out.println(str)
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `Character.isLowerCase(i)`. This will also work for non-ASCII letters.

Comment: Yes. That can also be used. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through the list and select the strings whose 1 element lies between `'a'` and `'z'`

```
 List<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
 for(String str: list){
     if(str.charAt(0)>='a' && str.charAt(0)<='z'){
         result.add(str);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full class with the final output printed:

```
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] testNames = new String[] { "StudentName", "ResigsterNumber", "Department", "grade", "comment" };

            List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            Arrays.asList(testNames).forEach((testCh) -> {
                if (testCh != null && !testCh.isEmpty() && Character.isLowerCase(testCh.charAt(0))) {
                    names.add(testCh);
                }
            });

            System.out.println(names);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the elements and put them through the following condition:

```
boolean hasLowerCase = element.equals(element.toLowerCase());
```

This will allow you to check:

```
if(hasLowerCase){System.out.println(Element is in lowercase)};
if(!hasLowerCase){System.out.println(Element is not in lowercase)};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String l : list){
    char character = l.charAt(0); // This gives the first character
    if (Character.isLowerCase(character)){
        // proceed with list element with small letter found
    }
}
```

Comment: `Character.isLowerCase(character)` is safer and more readable